# Compare 3 objects and show 1 as directed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to show a third gender "profile-others.png" denoted by "N". I'm still learning AngularJS and couldn't get it working except for Male/Female.

```
    {{session.user.profile.gender == 'M' ? 'images/profile-boy.png' : 'images/profile-girl.png'}}
```

How should i include a third .png file if a user choses N instead of M or F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest your ternary operator like this:

```
{{session.user.profile.gender == 'M' ? 'images/profile-boy.png' : session.user.profile.gender == 'F' ? 'images/profile-girl.png' : 'images/profile-others.png'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{{({'M': 'images/profile-boy.png', 'N': 'images/profilen.png', 'F': 'images/profile-girl.png'})[session.user.profile.gender]}}
```